# Ensure epmd started

Tags: erlang, eunit

I have an eunit test that generates a unique node name and starts distribution:

```
{A,B,C} = now(),
Nodename = list_to_atom(lists:flatten(io_lib:format(
    "test-~b-~b-~b@localhost", [A, B, C]))),
{ok, _} = net_kernel:start([Nodename, shortnames]),
```

This works fine as long as a distributed Erlang node has been running on the machine at some previous time, and thus epmd is still running, but on the build server I can't assume that's the case.

I solved the problem by adding this to my test:

```
_ = os:cmd("epmd -daemon"),
```

but it feels like a hack.  Is there a better/nicer way to ensure that epmd is started before running `net_kernel:start`?

Comment: How are you running your tests? If you start the erlang process as a node, by supplying `sname` or `name`, the process will implicitly ensure epmd is running for you.

Comment: I'm running the tests through `rebar eunit`.

Comment: I see. There's always [erl_opts](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/rebar.config.sample#L24) to add an name to, but that, as well, is kind of crummy.

Comment: ```os:cmd("epmd -daemon")``` will block if the epmd is not runing (tested on windows machine). How to get around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot ensure EPMD is started in a cleaner way.

**TL;DR**

EPMD is an external program, [implemented in C](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/epmd/src/epmd.c). Whilst `net_kernel:start/1` takes care of [creating the `net_sup` supervisor](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/erl_distribution.erl#L37), it does not actually trigger the EPMD daemon, which has to be started explicitely. I had a look at how EPMD is started when the `-sname` option is specified in the `erl` command and - surprise, surprise - I discovered that [the `epmd` program  is started via a `system()` C call](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/etc/common/erlexec.c#L1167-L1209).