# Is it possible to change the name of a running Elixir node

Tags: erlang, elixir, distributed

I want to change the node name of a beam instance dynamically.

The usecase is in a cluster of VM's I would like the startup process to lookup the ip information and then pick a name from that.

```
node()
# => :nonode@nohost

# Lookup ip and change name

node()
# => :myapp@x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [`net_kernel:start/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#start-1) in Erlang or [`Node.start/{1,2,3}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#start/3) in Elixir:

```
1> node().
nonode@nohost
2> net_kernel:start(['myapp@1.2.3.4']).
{ok,<0.60.0>}
(myapp@1.2.3.4)3> node().
'myapp@1.2.3.4'
```

```
iex(1)> Node.self
:nonode@nohost
iex(2)> Node.start :"myapp@1.2.3.4"
{:ok, #PID<0.83.0>}
iex(myapp@1.2.3.4)3> Node.self
:"myapp@1.2.3.4"
```

Comment: starting from a new iex shell I get an error when i try this.
{:error,
 {{:shutdown,
   {:failed_to_start_child, :net_kernel,
    {:EXIT,
     {:function_clause,
      [{:net_kernel, :start_link, [:"dev@172.28.128.7", false],
        [file: 'net_kernel.erl', line: 357]},

Comment: Looks like `epmd` is not running on the system. Check out this question and the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240319/ensure-epmd-started